# Cannot Fetch the Last_inserted_id in a foreach loop inside another foreach mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, winforms, ado

[image]

the image above shows the output inside mysql Tables.
my problem is it cannot get the value of last_inserted_id value in ORDERTABLE, as it is the reference value in ItemTable itemid.

this is my code in SAVEORDER and SAVEITEM

the description =is where I split the Data into a foreach and save it in item table.
each split should save each data with corresponding orderid, I tried last_inserted_id and not MaxID as i want it to be done by 1-3 user simultaneously without having problem in data integrity.

```
 private void SaveOrder()
        {
         
            try
                {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGSingleOrders.Rows)
                        {
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO single_order (customerid, category, type, description, code, color, price, status, transaction, attendee) VALUES (@customerid, @category, @type, @description, @code, @color, @price, @status, @transaction, @attendee)";
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.Connection = db.con;
                                db.con.Open();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OrderID;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@color", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SaveAs;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@transaction", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@attendee", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = attendee;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                db.con.Close();
                            }

                            //Check this first
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                                cmd.Connection = db.con;
                                db.con.Open();
                                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                          
                                    long id;
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        id = reader.GetInt64(0);
                                        ItemID = id.ToString();                                      
                                    }
                                    db.con.Close();
                                }
                         
                            }

               
                    
                         }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message,"ORDER");
                    db.con.Close();
                    return;
                }
            
        }
```

```
  private void SaveItem()
        {

            //Getting Each Data
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGSingleOrders.Rows)
            {
         
                string item = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string type = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string str = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                string code = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string color = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                List<string> descr = str.Split('+').ToList<string>();
                //Splitting Description

                //Adding Split to a DataTable

                foreach (var l in descr)
                {
                    OrderRow = l;

                        try
                        {
                            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO single_item (orderid, type, item, brand, code, color, eventdate, orderstatus, itemstatus, orderchecker, attendee)VALUES(@orderid, @type, @item, @brand, @code, @color, @eventdate, @orderstatus, @itemstatus, @orderchecker, @attendee)";
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.Connection = db.con;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@orderid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ItemID;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = type;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OrderRow;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@brand", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "-";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@color", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = color;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@eventdate", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = eventDay;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@orderstatus", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SaveAs;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemstatus", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Good";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@orderchecker", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Not Updated";
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@attendee", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = atendee;
                                db.con.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                db.con.Close();
                                dtItems.Clear();
                            }
                        }


                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                            db.con.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                    
                 SaveItem();
                }

            }
```

I added SaveItem(); Method inside SaveOrder(); ForeachLoop so that it can save together with the ORDER table, and can fetch the data of Last_inserted_id but it still get the first ID, I also tried putting it out the foreach loop, but then I can't get the result of the Order ID, and save data differently.

Comment: Regardless of your solution to your current issue, be aware that `cmd.Parameters.Add("@transaction", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt");` looks highly problematic. Why store a datetime in a column called `transaction`? And why store it as a string rather than as a datetime in the database?

Comment: I store it like that, because I convert it to many format, so a user can easily read it.
if i save it in native mysql date-time format, formatting it back gives me weird result, but Do you have any idea, how i can get the last insert id, on a loop? I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I can't help with your original problem. But the way you are storing dates is very poor. Formatting is a _display_ problem, not a _storage_ problem. You are taking more space, making it slow to search, wrecking opportunities for localisation, and just generally making your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I will change it,. Thank you for giving me advice.

Comment: One thing that might make your life easier is reading `cmd.LastInsertedId` after calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` for the `"INSERT INTO single_order..."` query. That will let you avoid the `"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"` query and is guaranteed to return the right value.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I don't know how would I get that value of that, will you show me some link on how to incorporate that? Sorry being too noob.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger hey bradley, can you post your comment as answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MySqlCommand.LastInsertedId` to get the ID of the row that was just inserted, without a separate query. It's also guaranteed to contain the correct value because it comes directly from MySQL's response to the `INSERT` statement.

```cs
long itemId;
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO single_order (customerid, ...";
    // ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    itemId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
}

// ...

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO single_item (orderid, ...";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", itemID);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figure it out.

Instead of using SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() which has some documentation that it only returns the first ID that has been insert. Bradley Grainger offer to use MySqlCommand.InsertLastId;

I've modified it to this.

````
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("newId", cmd.LastInsertedId));            
                        ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@newId"].Value);
                        MessageBox.Show(ItemID.ToString()); 
    ```
  now it is working. It can fetch the lastInserted iD in each loop, and the beauty of it is it can be threadsafe and can work along with simultaneous insert.

Also this link help me. https://livshitz.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/returning-last-inserted-id-in-c-using-mysql-db-provider/
````